# Django- How to set up abc's so that an instance of one refers to exactly one instance of each category

Tags: django, inheritance, django-models, polymorphism

I am using Django to implement a voting system. The voting consists of several categories, for which only one vote is allowed for each category. Let's, for instance, you had a vote on which teacher was best within each subject at a school. Your setup might look like this, with only one vote allowed per category per person:

```
Science:
  Teacher A
  Teacher B
  Teacher C

English
  Teacher D
  Teacher E

History
  Teacher F
  Teacher G
```

In this setup, for instance, a student could vote for teachers A, E, and F, but not for teachers A, B and G (because teachers A and B are within the same subject). How could I represent this with Option (an individual you can vote for), Category, and Vote abstract base classes in Django? In other words, how could you set it up generically such that each Vote instance has one reference to each Option instance (the Options that particular vote was for) but that none of its Options referred to the same category.

**Update**

To clarify, the solution should work for abstract base classes, such that inheritance automatically sets up whatever model relationships are used. For example, if the Option model is to have a FK to the Category model, I need a way for classes subclassing Option and Category to have their FK set up through the act of subclassing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need three tables, each with their own model inside Django: teachers table, categories table and Votes, teachers have a foreign key relationship to the categories table (unless they can be on several categories, then you need a many to many relationship), the votes table holds a fk to a teacher and a category and probably the id of the user that issued the vote.

Now the most important thing is ensuring that you can't vote twice in a single category, you can ensure this at the ORM level with this code, or you might want to also validate that after the user posts the voting form

```
class Vote(models.Model):
   teacher = models.ForeignKey("Teacher")
   category = models.ForeignKey("Category")
   voter = models.ForeignKey("User")

    def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
        votes = Vote.objects.filter(category=self.category,user=self.user)
        if len(votes)>0: #don't save a vote in the same category
            raise Exception("A vote has already been cast for this category")
        super(Vote,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

that save method ensures that a single user can't vote twice in the same category

Comment: Thanks for the response. A couple of questions.
1. Is save supposed to be an override within vote?
2. Each Vote should be able to pick one teacher in each category, does that mean this answer works with a little change, or that it is no longer viable?

Comment: yes the save method is an override of the Model save method, I edited my answer to better display python indentation, the solution is still viable as it is, even if a teacher might be part of several categories.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding. It's not that I need a teacher to be in multiple categories, it's that I need a vote to be able to vote for multiple categories. Also I don't believe you're solution deals with the inheritance problem.

Comment: yes, with this solution a single voter can vote for as many categories as he wants, as for your inheritance problem, remember that all subclasses inherit their parents properties, so if the base class has a foreign key, the subclass will inherit that too, if you will be dealing with that kind of class taxonomy I recommend you look into this library: https://github.com/chrisglass/django_polymorphic

Comment: So you're suggesting that a user can use multiple instances of the Vote class, one per category? As for the inheritance, I was more looking for something that can do this: http://djangotricks.blogspot.com/2009/02/abstract-models-and-dynamicly-assigned.html, except with the possibility of multiple subclasses.

Comment: yes that's exactly what I'm suggesting, you get the set of votes of a single user calling Vote.objects.filter(user=user) that way you can see his votes on each category. This solution will work if you (for some reason) need to subclass the Vote class, but if you subclass the category or teacher class it will break as you will need extra code to check business rules, once again ¿why would you need inheritance in this use case?

if this answer solves your problem please mark it as solved, ty